# Why do I get a different result when I call the *.mexw64 in Matlab second time?

Tags: matlab, fortran, mex

I used mex function to convert some fortran codes to matlab, and finally got myPET3copy.mexw64.
First time I call this fucntion, it goes well, but subsequently I call it second time, it returns
wrong result with NaN, and the same with the third time. Another fact is each time I re-compile this myPET3copy.mexw64, it goes well again the first time I called it. Does anyone know how to solve this
problem? Any help will be appreciated.

```
>> INPUT=[.42,.1,400.,.085,6000.,.675,1500.,.125,.125,300.,14.,.54,2.57,.33,.00036987];
>> OUTPUT=mexfunc(INPUT)

OUTPUT =

   1.0e+06 *

  Columns 1 through 7

    0.0060    0.0000    0.0015    0.0498    0.0000    8.1509    0.0001

  Column 8

    0.0000

>> OUTPUT=mexfunc(INPUT)

OUTPUT =

  Columns 1 through 6

        6002         NaN        1500         NaN         NaN         NaN

  Columns 7 through 8

         NaN         NaN

>>
```

Following is my mexFunction:

```
#include "fintrf.h"
    subroutine mexFunction(nlhs,plhs,nrhs,prhs)
    implicit none

    mwPointer plhs(*),prhs(*)
    integer*4 nlhs,nrhs
    mwPointer mxGetPr
    mwPointer mxCreateDoubleMatrix
    !integer*4 mxIsNumeric
    mwPointer mxGetM,mxGetN
    mwPointer input_ptr,output_ptr
    mwPointer mrows,ncols
    mwSize size
    COMMON/PAR/INPUT(15),OUTPUT(8)
    real*8 INPUT,OUTPUT
    mwSize :: ONE=1,EIGHT=8
    integer :: ComplexFlag=0
          
    mrows=mxGetM(prhs(1))
    ncols=mxGetN(prhs(1))
    size=mrows*ncols
    input_ptr=mxGetPr(prhs(1))
    call mxCopyPtrToReal8(input_ptr,INPUT,size)
    plhs(1)=mxCreateDoubleMatrix(ONE,EIGHT,ComplexFlag)
    output_ptr=mxGetPr(plhs(1))

      call myPET3()

    call mxCopyReal8ToPtr(output,output_ptr,EIGHT)

    return
    end
```

Comment: It sounds like your call to mexfunc also modifies your INPUT? Perhaps you could check that?

Comment: Does running `clear mexfunc` in between calling `mexfunc` solve the problem? If so, there’s static data in the MEX-file.

Comment: The problem could also be inside `myPET3()`. Please try to build a [mre].

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you, after runing"clear mexfunc" between two calls, the problem is solved.  I think I still need to improve my code. And the common block in my code may be the static data?

Comment: You probably have some static data somewhere. It could also be caused by reading uninitialized memory, though I'm uncertain how you'd get consistent results. The first time around it's filled with zeros, but after it contains previous data. Not sure why it'd be filled with zeros consistently unless it's a static data buffer. But in any case, this points towards a bug, clearing the MEX-file is a workaround, but you'd better fix the bug.